# YUI transition callback function not working on first click

Tags: yui, yui3

What the script does is, when you click on any child of this #viewPlan div it, I get the index of that child, and I show the same index div in the next sibling of #viewPlan

Following is the code, the problem is the callback function doesn't work when you click first time, it works fine from second click:

```
Y.all('#viewPlan > div').each(function(node, index){
    var planHeading = Y.one('#viewPlan').get('children');
    var planContent = Y.one('#viewPlan').next();
    var firstTime = true;
    planContent.get('children').addClass('display-none');
    node.on('click',function(em){
        em.currentTarget.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        planContent.get('children').item(index).siblings().transition({
            'easing': 'ease-out',
            'duration': 0.5,
            'opacity': 0
            }, function() { // problem starts here
                planContent.get('children').item(index).siblings().addClass('display-none');
                planContent.get('children').item(index).removeClass('display-none');
                planContent.get('children').item(index).transition({
                    'easing': 'ease-out',
                    'duration': 0.5,
                    'opacity': 1
                });
            });

        });
});
```

If something is not clear, please let me know.